# Can not save python pickled file in spark yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I submit spark code to yarn, and in the code, I want to save a python pickled file, but it failed with `FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory`, my code:

```
pdf = spark_df.select("select a, b from table").toPandas()
with open('./myfile', 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(pdf, f)
```

I substitute `./myfile` with `file:///myfile` or hdfs file, but it still show that error. How can I save this pickled file to local or hdfs?

Comment: you do realize that `./myfile` != `file:///myfile`, right? the former points to PWD, while the latter points to the top level directory (both on local FS)

Comment: Yes, I use `file:///myfile` as the local file path, but it still raised FileNotFoundError.

Comment: but is the file really in `/myfile`? or in `./myFile` ?